# Newly added UI elements arent appearing on my program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have made the program below, and have added on the two new buttons, "Submit" and "Quit", however when i run my program they do not appear, and the UI is unchanged from before and after.

This is my program:

```
import tkinter as tk

def Validate_number():
    value = entry_1.get()
    if value.isnumeric() == True:
        value = float(value)
        if value <= 1 and value >= 100:
            label_1.config(text = "Valid input")
        else:
            label_1.config(text = "Invalid input, please try again")

    else:
        label_1.config(text = "Invalid input, please try again")



window = tk.Tk()
value = None

label_1 = tk.Label(text = "Enter your explosive value, between 1 and 100Kt equivilant")
label_1.grid(row= 0, column= 0)
button_1 = tk.Button(text = "Submit", command = Validate_number)
button_1.grid(row= 0, column= 1)
button_2 = tk.Button(text = "Quit", command = window.destroy)
button_2.grid(row = 1, coulmn = 1)
entry_1 = tk.Entry()
entry_1.grid(row= 0, column= 2)

window.mainloop()
```

This problem has been quite persistent, and isn't allowing me to test if the validation section of the code will work, or if it needs changing

Comment: misspelled the word "column" as "coulmn"

Comment: You need to create another labe_2 = Label widget and replace label_1.config with label_2.config

Comment: You cannot use a float for `isnumeric()`.